# Get a file's path from a file chooser dialog in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, csv, path, openfiledialog

I would like to import some CSV files in my application, but the application only needs the full path of the file. If I hard-code the file's path in the application, it works well, but I want the user himself to choose his own file by a file chooser dialog (like the JFileChooser in Java). From this, I would like to get the path of the selected file. Is there anyone that can help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody else answered this ???

The simplest way is with the gem green_shoes which you install with

```
gem install green_shoes
```

See http://ashbb.github.com/green_shoes/

Then in your script

```
require 'green_shoes'
filename = ask_open_file
```

That's it